# crosswalk/engine/XWalkWebViewEngine.java:50: error: cannot find symbol

Tags: android, ionic-framework, crosswalk

I am getting above mentioned error when i add crosswalk to my project.here i am attaching screen-shot of error :-

[image]

i even tried with :- cordova plugin add https://github.com/crosswalk-project/cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview.git

but still getting same error as above.If i do not add crosswalk my application works fine, this issue only comes if i add crossWalk.

I even tried with ionic browser add crosswalk@12.41.296.5..but again no help from this too

Any help will be appreciated ,

Thanks

Comment: I think the issue is of asking Permissions at runtime. Android M introduced concept of asking permissions at runtime. Have a look here: - http://coderzpassion.com/android-new-runtime-permissions/

Comment: please show your manifest.

Comment: ok i saw it. so did you asked for those permission at runtime ? (as you have 23 as target)