# Could not find gradle wrapper within Android SDK. Might need to update your Android SDK

Tags: android, cordova, ionic2, android-sdk-tools

I am trying to take build in an ionic2 application. I got this error while running `ionic build android`. The error log is

```
ANDROID_HOME=/home/varun/Android/Sdk
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
Error: Could not find gradle wrapper within Android SDK. Might need to    update your Android SDK.
Looked here: /home/varun/Android/Sdk/tools/templates/gradle/wrapper
```

I tried updating the sdk but it was found that the sdk version is latest.

When i looked at the `Android/Sdk/tools` folder there is no `templates` directory. I am running on ubuntu 16.04, with cordova version `6.5.0`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42613882/error-could-not-find-gradle-wrapper-within-android-sdk-might-need-to-update-yo

Comment: @suraj thanks. That solved the issue.

Answer (score 83):

Edit:

There has been a newer release of Cordova Android that also fixes some problems with SDK tools 26.x.x

`cordova platform update android@6.2.2`

or

```
cordova platform rm android
cordova platform add android@6.2.2
```

Old answer

Google broke Cordova Android 6.1.x and some other frameworks with their latest sdk tools update.

Cordova Android 6.2.1 has been released and it's now compatible with latest Android SDK.

You can update your current incompatible android platform with `cordova platform update android@6.2.1`

Or you can remove the existing platform and add the new one (will delete any manual change you did inside yourProject/platforms/android/ folder)

`cordova platform rm android
cordova platform add android@6.2.1`

You have to specify the version because current CLI installs 6.1.x by default.

Comment: Didn't fix the issue for me.

Comment: @dsp_099 did you remove android platform first? if you run  `cordova platforms` what cordova-android version do you get?

Comment: I see "Installed platforms: android 6.1.2. See latest question on my profile for more info"

Comment: then do a `cordova platform rm android` first and then `cordova platform add https://github.com/apache/cordova-android`, you should get 6.2.0-dev instead of 6.1.2

Comment: Step in the right direction... That helped... [sort of](http://pastebin.com/enRYxNa9). See my [question here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42925597/android-studio-doesnt-install-sdks-what/42926194#42926194), seems to be the issue, might give you more intel.

Comment: Thanks that fixed it for me after updating SDK tools to 25.3.1

Comment: I get a warning:
 cmd: command failed with exit code 1
Can i get rid of it somehow?

Comment: @Azarus which command?

Comment: When upgrading the android platform, this seems pretty messed up right now. :/ Spent like 4 hours just setting things up huh

Comment: Thanks man, this worked fine for me

Comment: You little beauty.

Comment: Fantastic. Running `cordova platform update android` worked perfectly. It updated to 6.2.3. It must know to look for gradle in the new directory: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\plugins\android\lib\templates\gradle\wrapper

Comment: How is 6.2.2 a newer release when OP has 6.5.0 ?
The two solutions to this problem involve either downgrading Android SDK or Cordova, it doesn't seem like a very sustainable solution - you're going to have to upgrade eventually right?

Comment: @ChickenFeet No, you are confusing cordova-lib (or Cordova CLI) version with cordova-android version. Cordova CLI 6.5.0 had cordova-android 6.1.1, so, by the time I wrote this, he needed to upgrade the cordova-android version to 6.2.2. Now there is a new Cordova CLI version (7.0.1) that uses cordova-android 6.2.x as default.

Comment: cordova platform update android@6.2.2 fixed my issue. thanks bro..:)

Comment: @LAnantaPrasad at this point you also have 6.4.0 or 7.1.4 available, that also have the problem fixed and are newer

Comment: @jcesarmobile thanks

Comment: This is working for me thanks dude......

Answer (score 47):

I resolved by this by replacing the `tools` folder in my Android SDK with an older version of the SDK tools (`r25.2.3`). Follow these steps to do the same:

1. Navigate to https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html, click "Download Options", scroll down, and download the command line tools package for your platform, ensuring that you get a version in the `r25.2.X` series (*not* `r25.3.X`).
2. Unzip this folder. You should end up with a `tools` directory.
3. Navigate to your `$ANDROID_HOME` directory (`~/Library/Android/sdk/` on OS X).
4. Rename the pre-existing `tools` directory there to `tools.bak` (e.g., `mv tools tools.bak`)
5. Move the `tools` directory you just downloaded into the SDK folder (e.g., `mv ~/Downloads/tools/ .`)

A new major version of the SDK tools was just released, which appears to be causing some issues with Ionic (see the press release here: http://tools.android.com/recent/androidsdktoolsrevision2530feb2017).

Comment: DETAILS PLEASE, how do you "Change tools directory to tools_r25.2.3 directory."?

Comment: I think he meant to put all the files from r25.3.1 on the previously installed tools folder.

Comment: Indeed, downloading the latest command line tools and paste its content in the /Android/sdk/tools folder solved the problem ;)

Comment: AFAIKT I was able to get away with just copying the old tools/templates subdirectory into the Android/sdk/tools folder.

Comment: Yes It WORKED thankks

Comment: Thank you! 
It's really works!

Comment: it worked, thanks :)

Comment: I've been working on this for 3 days. You save my life. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me

`cordova platform update android@6.1.2`

Comment: you sure you don;t mean @6.2.1?

Comment: I am sure, that is the version I am using

Comment: This did *not* work for me. It still gave the same "can't find gradle wrapper" comment

Answer (score 4):

There's no need to downgrade Android Tools.
On Windows gradle moved from:

C:\Users\you_username\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools

to:

C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\plugins\android\lib\templates\gradle\wrapper

So you just need to ajust your path so that it points to the right folder.

Comment: where do we adjust it? in cordova?

Comment: @mentat update it in the windows path.

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem and I solved it with Carlos Delgado's answer.

- Android Path must be set before all things below.
- Download the latest command line tools (https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html -> very bottom part)
- Unzip -> copy and paste "tools > templates" folder to your project folder (/Libraries/Android/sdk/tools/)
- press option key to see Libraries folder in your Finder

Comment: Can you explain better, excuse me, i don't get the part, *tools > templates*, i need copy the tools folder into template, o what project you say?