# Android Studio doesn't install SDKs... what?

Tags: android, cordova, android-studio, phonegap-build, android-sdk-tools

I'm trying to use Cordova to build a hello world app and after adding `ANDROID_HOME` variable (You'd be shocked how long that took to figure out) all I keep seeing when building is this:

> BUILD FAILED
>
> Total time: 1 mins 6.679 secs Error:
>   /Users/vladdy/Desktop/laboratory/cordovaBackgroundApp/platforms/android/gradlew:
>   Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
>
> FAILURE: Build failed
>   with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
>
>   > Failed to find target with hash string 'android-25' in: /Users/vladdy/Library/Android/sdk
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

Ok fair enough so let's go install it:

[image]

Waiting patiently for the install, and same error running `cordova build`.

I wonder what else we need to install? But look, it seems that Android Studio still has Nougat and 25 available:

[image]

### Why is Android Studio not installing anything?

I can see why PhoneGap Build is so popular...

#### Edit:

`cordova requirements` is now broken reporting the following:

[image]

My `~/.bash_profile`:

`export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/vladdy/Library/Android/sdk/`

Comment: How does your `config.xml` look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Requirements?

If you don't need Android Studio, I recommend not downloading it, instead, as @Tom-Esendam also suggest, go for the command-line tool.

[Android Studio and Command Line Tool](https://developer.android.com/studio/)

[Direct download link of Command Line Tool for OSX](https://dl.google.com/android/repository/tools_r25.2.3-macosx.zip) (2017-03-21)

### Proxy?

And if your behind a proxy server, don't forget to add it to the settings in the SDK Manager Settings.

### What does the different programs and commands?

`cordova build` doesn't download any SDK's.

`cordova prepare` appends the necessary SDK files to the cordova build folders.

### After download of Command Line Tool:

After unzipping it, set `ANDROID_HOME` to it's root, so you have:

- build-tools
- extras
- platforms
- platform-tools
- system-images
- tools

catalogs under the root.

### Adding SDK's:

Then install SDK's with `./tools/android`.
Android SDK Manager downloads the SDK's, so you `check` what you need and hit `OK` to download it.

### Preparing the build

1. Make sure all proxy settings are set if your behind a proxy.
2. Before running `cordova build` run `cordova prepare`. This shouldn't be necessary, but least I need to run that even thou `cordova build` should include that.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about the mac version. But on windows you have a standalone sdk manager. If there is one on mac try that?